# How to call the 'nth' slide?

Tags: jquery, methods

I need to access the methods of 'going to a specific slide' (like slide (0) or (1)..) using a 'jquery' slider.. the slider function starts with:

the slideshow function:

```
var cbpBGSlideshow = (function() {

var $slideshow = $( '#cbp-bislideshow' ),
    $items = $slideshow.children( 'li' ),
    itemsCount = $items.length,
    $controls = $( '#cbp-bicontrols' ),
    navigation = {
        $navPrev : $controls.find( 'span.cbp-biprev' ),
        $navNext : $controls.find( 'span.cbp-binext' ),
        $navPlayPause : $controls.find( 'span.cbp-bipause' )
    },
    // current item´s index
    current = 0,
    // timeout
    slideshowtime,
    // true if the slideshow is active
    isSlideshowActive = true,
    // it takes 3.5 seconds to change the background image
    interval = 3500;

function init( config ) {

    // preload the images
    $slideshow.imagesLoaded( function() {

        if( Modernizr.backgroundsize ) {
            $items.each( function() {
                var $item = $( this );
                $item.css( 'background-image', 'url(' + $item.find( 'img' ).attr( 'src' ) + ')' );
            } );
        }
        else {
            $slideshow.find( 'img' ).show();
            // for older browsers add fallback here (image size and centering)
        }
        // show first item
        $items.eq( current ).css( 'opacity', 1 );
        // initialize/bind the events
        initEvents();
        // start the slideshow
        startSlideshow();

    } );

}

function initEvents() {

    navigation.$navPlayPause.on( 'click', function() {

        var $control = $( this );
        if( $control.hasClass( 'cbp-biplay' ) ) {
            $control.removeClass( 'cbp-biplay' ).addClass( 'cbp-bipause' );
            startSlideshow();
        }
        else {
            $control.removeClass( 'cbp-bipause' ).addClass( 'cbp-biplay' );
            stopSlideshow();
        }

    } );

    navigation.$navPrev.on( 'click', function() { 
        navigate( 'prev' ); 
        if( isSlideshowActive ) { 
            startSlideshow(); 
        } 
    } );
    navigation.$navNext.on( 'click', function() { 
        navigate( 'next' ); 
        if( isSlideshowActive ) { 
            startSlideshow(); 
        }
    } );

}

function navigate( direction ) {

    // current item
    var $oldItem = $items.eq( current );

    if( direction === 'next' ) {
        current = current < itemsCount - 1 ? ++current : 0;
    }
    else if( direction === 'prev' ) {
        current = current > 0 ? --current : itemsCount - 1;
    }

    // new item
    var $newItem = $items.eq( current );
    // show / hide items
    $oldItem.css( 'opacity', 0 );
    $newItem.css( 'opacity', 1 );

}

function startSlideshow() {

    isSlideshowActive = true;
    clearTimeout( slideshowtime );
    slideshowtime = setTimeout( function() {
        navigate( 'next' );
        startSlideshow();
    }, interval );

}

function stopSlideshow() {
    isSlideshowActive = false;
    clearTimeout( slideshowtime );
}

return { init : init };

})();
```

Sorry to the lengthy code but if someone could come up with something it would be just great..

A working example with controllers is available at:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/background-slideshow/

js file: cbpBGSlideshow.min.js

Comment: [Link to project on GitHub](https://github.com/codrops/Blueprint-BackgroundSlideshow). Looks like there's no support in the source code for navigating to an arbitrary slide, the `navigate` function only checks for `'next'` and `'prev'`.

Comment: the point is that I didn't able to call any function inside the js.. the entire function is called in <script/> tag as:

$(function() {
 cbpBGSlideshow.init();    
});